# get dates and times from database and have an alarm

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, winforms

[image: table from which i am taking date and time![][1]]

I have a method called GetAlarm(),which I am using in form_load. My alarm is not getting raised. For example, the date today is 29 jan 2014. and currently the time is 8:30 AM and in the database I have on 29 jan first alarm at time 8:35AM, then second at 8:45AM, then third at 8:50AM, then when I run the Application on 8:30AM then there will be alarm on 8:35AM and then I can snooze or close the alarm if I close it then it should take the next 8:45AM alarm and I dont have to re-run the application.

```
private void GetAlarm()
        {
            if (Collection.SelectQuery("SELECT CONVERT(varchar, Date, 111) FROM Mst_Event WHERE (CONVERT(varchar, Date, 111) = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 111))") == true)
            {
                ListBox lst = new ListBox();
                Collection.FillList(lst, "SELECT time FROM Mst_Event WHERE (CONVERT(varchar, Date, 111) = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 111))");
                for (int i = 0; i < lst.Items.Count; i++)
                {                    
                    string AmPm = Collection.getData("SELECT AmPm FROM Mst_Event WHERE (CONVERT(varchar, Date, 111) = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 111)) and time='" + lst.Items[i].ToString() + "'");
                    var datenow = DateTime.Now;
                    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
                    if (AmPm.ToUpper() == "AM")
                    {
                        dt = new DateTime(datenow.Year, datenow.Month, datenow.Day, Convert.ToInt32(lst.Items[i].ToString().Substring(0, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(lst.Items[i].ToString().Substring(3, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(lst.Items[i].ToString().Substring(6, 2)));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dt = new DateTime(datenow.Year, datenow.Month, datenow.Day, Convert.ToInt32(lst.Items[i].ToString().Substring(0, 2)) + 12, Convert.ToInt32(lst.Items[i].ToString().Substring(3, 2)), Convert.ToInt32(lst.Items[i].ToString().Substring(6, 2)));
                    }
                    if (dt > DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        AlarmTime = Convert.ToInt32(lst.Items[i].ToString().Substring(0, 2)) + ":" + Convert.ToInt32(lst.Items[i].ToString().Substring(3, 2)) + " " + AmPm;
                        i = lst.Items.Count;
                    }
                }
            }
            this.Text = "Alarm Clock - Set: " + AlarmTime;
        }
```

Please help me I am trying this solution for more than two weeks.

Comment: "My alarm is not getting raised" - What does this mean?
What are the values of the items in `lst`?
What is the point of this if you have to be lucky enough to "run" the winForms app at precisely the moment when an alarm time is set? There is probably a better way to accomplish whatever it is that you are trying to do.

Comment: i am storing the dates and time in a list after getting it from database of the present day, so that I can catch the latest time of alarm,and all the today's alarm will be in the list

Comment: I have alarm clock which is taking time which i type in the textbox and match it with the current time, and then there is an alarm, but i want the alarm clock should take the time from database

Comment: @user3186703 Can you send me your database tables rows. I feel you are not formatting datetime properly.

Comment: @Shashank Date-date,Time-time(7), AmPm-nvarchar(50). My friend please help in this, if you need more details i will give you.

Comment: @user3186703 edit your question and add rows of your database tables. So i can get a clear idea of it.

Comment: @Shashank I wanted upload an image of the database but its asking for more reputation so i have edited like above

Comment: @Shashank My friend is this right.

Comment: @user3186703 At what event r u calling this GetAlarm function.

Comment: @Shashank I have written that in my question that is " I am using in form_load"

Comment: @user3186703 You should run your code in timer tick event so that it is called again and again to check the time. Use Timer control in windows. Google it how to use timer you will get your solution.

Comment: Thanks @Shashank i have used timer and its working as i wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used one timer and in its tick event I have called this Method GetAlarm() such that

```
if (AlarmTime == "")
        {            
        GetAlarm();
        }
```

and i have used one button so that when the alarm is raised that button will be shown and when the user clicks it that current alarm will get closed and because of timer it will check for the next alarm.